# Msal.js getUser() returns null

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

When I use the msal.js library after successfully authorizing the user, I am getting a `null` response on `getUser()` and am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that `getUser()` is called inside `tokenReceivedcallback`. The `tokenReceivedcallback` function is the guaranteed way of knowing whether the login is successful.